# Add views and set layout_toRightOf programatically - first view not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout

I am adding a few custom views in RelativeLayout in java using the code below and **addRule** to align it to right of previously added view but the view added at 1st iteration is now showing up (Rest of the views appear fine).

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
int pegIds[] = {Peg.BLUE, Peg.GREEN, Peg.RED, Peg.WHITE, Peg.YELLOW, Peg.PURPLE};
Peg peg;

for (int i = 0; i < pegIds.length; i++) {
    peg = new Peg(context, null);
    peg.setId(i);
    peg.setTag("hotbar_" + i);
    peg.setDrawableID(pegIds[i]);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (i > 0)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i-1);
    hotbar.addView(peg, params);
}
```

RelativeLayout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/hotbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" ></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `requestLayout()` on hotbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think a view can have an Id of 0

try

```
for (int i = 1000; i < 1000 + pegIds.length; i++) {
```

Comment: It worked! Awesome! So is it just 0 or are there any other restrictions on id?

Comment: great!

You cant have an id of 0, or a negative number, and you must make sure that IDs are never used twice, or there will be problems.

Comment: I normally used

    public static int FIRST_ID_ACTIVITY_1 = 1000;
    public static int FIRST_ID_ACTIVITY_2 = 2000;
    public static int FIRST_ID_ACTIVITY_3 = 3000;
    public static int FIRST_ID_ACTIVITY_4 = 4000;
    
    for (int i = FIRST_ID_ACTIVITY_1; i < FIRST_ID_ACTIVITY_1 + pegIds.length; i++) {